# Hive: where + in does not use partition?

Tags: hive, partitioning

I am querying a large table that is partitioned on a field called `day`. 
If I run a query:

`select *
from my_table
where day in ('2016-04-01', '2016-03-01')`

I get many mappers and reducers and the query takes a long time to run.

If, however, I write a query:

`select * 
from my_table
where day = '2016-04-01' 
or day = '2016-03-01'`

I get far less mappers and reducers and the query runs quickly. **To me this suggests that `in` does not take advantage of partitions in a table. Can anyone confirm this and explain why?**

Hive Version: 1.2.1
Hadoop Version: 2.3.4.7-4

Details:
I believe the relevant part of the execution plans are...

Using `Where or`
No filter operator at all
Using `Where in` 
`Filter Operator
              predicate: (day) IN ('2016-04-01', '2016-03-01') (type: boolean)
              Statistics: Num rows: 100000000 Data size: 9999999999`

[The hive docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-PartitionBasedQuery) just say: 
'What partitions to use in a query is determined automatically by the system on the basis of where clause conditions on partition columns.'

But don't elaborate. I couldn't find any SO posts directly relating to this.

Thanks!

Comment: And the same with `between` operator

Comment: This issue exists in Hive 1.2.0

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

I am using **Hive 1.1.0** with **Cloudera 5.13.3** and `IN` follows the same optimization as the equal operator (`=`) according to the explain plans I ran in Hue.

---

### Examples

My table is partitioned on `LOAD_YEAR (SMALLINT)` and `LOAD_MONTH (TINYINT)` and has these two partitions:

1. `load_year=2018/load_month=10` (19,828,71 rows)
2. `load_year=2018/load_month=11` (702,856 rows)

Below are various queries and their explain plans.

**1. Equal (`=`) operator**

Query:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TBL
WHERE LOAD_MONTH = 11Y
```

Explain Plan:

```
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-0 is a root stage

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: -1
      Processor Tree:
        TableScan
          alias: tbl
          filterExpr: (load_month = 11) (type: boolean)
          Statistics: Num rows: 702856 Data size: 84342720 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
          Select Operator
            expressions: id (type: string)
            outputColumnNames: _col0
            Statistics: Num rows: 702856 Data size: 84342720 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            ListSink
```

**2. `IN` operator**

Query (*note that there is no month 12 in the data*):

```
SELECT ID
FROM TBL
WHERE LOAD_MONTH IN (11Y, 12Y)
```

Explain Plan:

```
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-0 is a root stage

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: -1
      Processor Tree:
        TableScan
          alias: tbl
          filterExpr: (load_month = 11) (type: boolean)
          Statistics: Num rows: 702856 Data size: 84342720 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
          Select Operator
            expressions: id (type: string)
            outputColumnNames: _col0
            Statistics: Num rows: 702856 Data size: 84342720 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            ListSink
```

**3. Equal (`=`) in conjunction with AND and OR**

Query:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TBL
WHERE
    (LOAD_YEAR = 2018S AND LOAD_MONTH = 11Y)
OR  (LOAD_YEAR = 2019S AND LOAD_MONTH = 1Y)
```

Explain Plan:

```
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-0 is a root stage

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: -1
      Processor Tree:
        TableScan
          alias: tbl
          filterExpr: (((load_year = 2018) and (load_month = 11)) or ((load_year = 2019) and (load_month = 1))) (type: boolean)
          Statistics: Num rows: 702856 Data size: 84342720 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
          Select Operator
            expressions: id (type: string)
            outputColumnNames: _col0
            Statistics: Num rows: 702856 Data size: 84342720 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            ListSink
```

**4. Arithmetic operation**

Query:

```
SELECT ID
FROM TBL
WHERE (LOAD_YEAR * 100 + LOAD_MONTH) IN (201811, 201901)
```

Side note:

100 doesn't have a suffix, so it's an `INT`, and `(LOAD_YEAR * 100 + LOAD_MONTH)` is also an `INT`. This ensures that the result is accurate. Since `LOAD_YEAR` is a `SMALLINT` and `LOAD_MONTH` a `TINYINT`, arithmetic calculations on the two use `SMALLINT` for the results and the max value stored is 32,767 (not enough for `yyyymm`, which needs 6 digits, i.e., at least up to 999,999). With 100 as an `INT`, calculations are made with the `INT` type and allow numbers up to 2,147,483,647.

Explain Plan:

```
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-0 is a root stage

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: -1
      Processor Tree:
        TableScan
          alias: tbl
          filterExpr: (201811) IN (201811, 201901) (type: boolean)
          Statistics: Num rows: 702856 Data size: 84342720 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
          Select Operator
            expressions: id (type: string)
            outputColumnNames: _col0
            Statistics: Num rows: 702856 Data size: 84342720 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
            ListSink
```

**Summary**

All these queries only scan the second partition, thereby avoiding the ~20 million rows in the other partition.